# Jquery: Do different things depending on return of $.post()

Tags: jquery

I have this code to add a user:

```
$.post('ajax/aj_adduser.php', $("form#adduserform").serialize(), function(result) {
disablePopup();             $('#addsuccess').delay(200).fadeToggle('slow').delay(2000).fadeToggle('slow');  
$('div.mainadmin').html(result);            
});
```

which works almost fine :-)
The problem is, that the line:

```
$('#addsuccess').delay(200).fadeToggle('slow').delay(2000).fadeToggle('slow');
```

should only be executed if the user was added, so not if the result set contains the message that this user already exists.

How do I fix this? I first tried to execute upon success or not of the POST, but it always succeeds, it is just the outcome, the result set that is different.

All help appreciated!

Comment: What information are your returning as a response to your request?

Comment: Have you tried examining `result` in your callback and using that in something like an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('ajax/aj_adduser.php', $("form#adduserform").serialize(), function(result) {
    disablePopup();   
    if(result.YourMessage == ...){
        $('#addsuccess').delay(200).fadeToggle('slow').delay(2000).fadeToggle('slow');     
    }  
    else{ ... }        
    $('div.mainadmin').html(result);            
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this method to check for a particular string in the result, and got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's AJAX functions will return the data from the AJAX call to the function where you attempt to call that line. You can access the result set you get from `result` in your function.

This means you can check the data that is returned and do things conditionally with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the php file in ajax/aj_adduser.php returns a status parameter.

something like this:

```
if ($useradded){
   $rt->status = "useradded";
   $rt->result = $result;
}else{
   $rt->status = "failed";
}
echo json_encode($rt);
```

you can change your $.post call to $.getJSON, and check the result like so:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/aj_adduser.php', $("form#adduserform").serialize(), function(result) {
    if (result.status = "useradded"){
        // do something
        $('div.mainadmin').html(result.result); 
    }else{
       // don't do anything
    }
}
```

Comment: Love this way of getting it fixed, although for this particular project, I choose the other answer, I will keep this one in my "list"! Thank you!